# Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0"

Tags: raspbian, linux, xorg, vnc

I'm trying to run openvibe-designer on my raspberry pie over vnc. Currently I am using Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9. All other applications that I've launched over vnc have worked. I only get this error when I run openvibe-designer. Any tips on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do this: sudo dmesg -c then run openvibe, then see what dmesg says. I think youre missing a library in your path. But, Im not sure.

Comment: I did what you suggested and after attempting to run openvibe dmesg didn't have anything to output.

Answer (score 1):

X11 is a protocol that has grown quite a bit over the years, and where the natural place to put new functionality was in so-called "extensions".   The error message indicates that the program you want to run, uses an extension that Xvnc does not have.

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr:

> xrandr is an official configuration utility to the RandR (Resize and
>   Rotate) X Window System extension. It can be used to set the size,
>   orientation or reflection of the outputs for a screen.

To my knowledge there is no simple workaround.   You can, however, install an X11 server on the computer you actually use and then tell openvibe-designer to use that instead.  For ssh connections use `ssh -Y raspberry` in a session that has the DISPLAY variable set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening .bashrc file using fofllowing command

```
sudo nano /.bashrc
```

add this line to the code.

```
xhost +
```

Comment: And why should disabling access control help?